# MAX value from specific rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables student, subject and scores

```
CREATE TABLE `student` (
  `student_id` INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `student_name` VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`student_id`));

CREATE TABLE `subject` (
  `subject_id` INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `subject_name` VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`subject_id`));

CREATE TABLE `scores` (
  `student_id` INTEGER NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `subject_id` INTEGER NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `score` INTEGER NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY (`student_id`, `subject_id`));

ALTER TABLE `scores` ADD FOREIGN KEY (student_id) REFERENCES `student` (`student_id`);
ALTER TABLE `scores` ADD FOREIGN KEY (subject_id) REFERENCES `subject` (`subject_id`);

INSERT INTO student VALUES (1, 'John');
INSERT INTO student VALUES (2, 'Harry');
INSERT INTO student VALUES (3, 'Dick');

INSERT INTO subject VALUES (1, 'Math');
INSERT INTO subject VALUES (2, 'History');
INSERT INTO subject VALUES (3, 'Physics');

INSERT INTO scores VALUES (1, 1, 50);
INSERT INTO scores VALUES (1, 2, 35);
INSERT INTO scores VALUES (1, 3, 40);

INSERT INTO scores VALUES (2, 1, 20);
INSERT INTO scores VALUES (2, 2, 65);
INSERT INTO scores VALUES (2, 3, 70);

INSERT INTO scores VALUES (3, 1, 30);
INSERT INTO scores VALUES (3, 2, 25);
INSERT INTO scores VALUES (3, 3, 50);
```

I want to write a query to get the ID and name of the student who has done best in the test with a subject_id of 1.
I have tried the following:

```
SELECT student.student_id, scores.score, subject.subject_id, student.student_name
FROM scores
INNER JOIN student ON scores.student_id=student.student_id
INNER JOIN subject ON scores.subject_id=subject.subject_id
Where subject.subject_id=1 AND scores.score=(SELECT MAX(score))
```

However, I have unable to restrict it to the highest score. Please help.

```
student_id  score   subject_id  student_name
1   50  1   John
2   20  1   Harry
3   30  1   Dick
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd be inclined to use a sub-query to achieve this, which would first find the student with the highest score in the `scores` table for the subject:

```
SELECT  student_id, subject_id, score
  FROM  scores
  WHERE subject_id = 1
  ORDER BY score DESC
  LIMIT 1;
```

Note that I added `LIMIT 1` to return only the student with the highest score for that subject.

Next `JOIN` the subquery with your output tables like so:

```
SELECT  st.student_id, a.score, su.subject_id, st.student_name
  FROM  (
        SELECT  student_id, subject_id, score
          FROM  scores
          WHERE subject_id = 1
          ORDER BY score DESC
          LIMIT 1
        ) a
    INNER JOIN subject su ON su.subject_id = a.subject_id
    INNER JOIN student st ON st.student_id = a.student_id;
```

This outputs:

```
student_id score subject_id student_name
1          50    1          John
```

Here's a [working fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9i1gy9hZmVoESudNnrUU6a/0) showing this in action.

Comment: It just occurs to me that in the case of two or more students sharing the highest score, the above answer would not work (because it will only return one of the students).  If that is something that you may need to achieve please advise me and I'll look again